# Como Hacer para que me muestre el gmaps sin ninguna restriccion

Tags: javascript, google-maps

estoy intentando crear unos graficos con gmaps.js pero la grafica me sale de esta manera

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

como ven me sale qel mensaje de "esta pagina no puede cargar Google Maps correctamente" y un fondo medio opaco como restringiendo con un sello que dice "For development purposes only"

el codigo es el siguiente

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>GMaps.js &mdash; Markers</title>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../gmaps.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/1.3.0/bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="examples.css" />
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
$(document).ready(function(){
  map = new GMaps({
    el: '#map',
    lat: -12.043333,
    lng: -77.028333
  });
  map.addMarker({
    lat: -12.043333,
    lng: -77.03,
    title: 'Lima',
    details: {
      database_id: 42,
      author: 'HPNeo'
    },
    click: function(e){
      if(console.log)
        console.log(e);
      alert('You clicked in this marker');
    },
    mouseover: function(e){
      if(console.log)
        console.log(e);
    }
  });
  map.addMarker({
    lat: -12.042,
    lng: -77.028333,
    title: 'Marker with InfoWindow',
    infoWindow: {
      content: '<p>HTML Content</p>'
    }
  });
  });
 </script>
</head>
<body>
<h1>GMaps.js </h1>
<div class="row">
<div class="span11">
    <div id="map"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

como puedo hacer para que el fondo me salga claro sin ese tipo de restricciones?

Answer (score 2):

Necesitas obtener una **API key** de Google Cloud Platform Console y agregarla en:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true&key=TU_API_KEY"></script>
```